# What is/isn't allowed in the long view of a rich notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been tasked with updating my company's app to handle rich push notifications. I am having a hard time find a hard list of what will/will not work in the long view of the notification. So here are my main questions.

- Am I able to present web views?
- Are network request able to be
  handled in the long view, or do all resources need to be downloaded
  before the notification is sent?
- Is there any user interaction
  available in the long view outside of the UNNotificationActions?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. We are still planning things out at the moment and I thought I would try saving some time effort by asking here. Hoping someone would know the answers.

Thanks for the answer about interaction.

Comment: I have other task I need to do to. This is not something that is a priority for me to start working on at the moment. But we are grooming the idea. I figured it would be faster to just ask and see if anyone knew. 

I'm pretty new to all of this so it wouldn't only take 10 minutes. It would be a good amount of time for me. So asking would be faster.